# Do I need OAuth - Google Contact Form data (all) to Sheet then to Email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-oauth, google-forms

I want to use Google Form as a contact form on a website, and email the contents of the form (not just a notification) to a specified address.

I created a Google Form, embedded it on a website to use as a contact form for enquiries. Then created a Sheet to pull in the data from the Form. After that I created a Trigger for onFormSubmission which runs the following:

```
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */
function onFormSubmission (e) {
  var values = e.namedValues;
  var htmlBody ='<ul>';
  for (Key in values) {
  var label = Key;
  var data = values[Key];
  htmlBody += '<li>' + label + ": " + data + '</li>';
  Logger.log(label + ": " + data);
};
  htmlBody += '</ul>';
  GmailApp.sendEmail('me@gmail.com', 'Web Form Enquiry', '', {htmlBody:htmlBody})
}
```

Running this brings up a dialogue stating:

> Authorization required.
>
> 'Send email' needs your permission to access your data on Google
>   Review Permissions or Cancel

['Send email' is my 'App' in G Suite]

Clicking Review Permissions opens a popup asking to choose an account to continue. Clicking on the account (the same account I'm logged in with and have created the form, etc with) brings up:

> This app isn't verified. This app hasn't been verified by Google yet. Only proceed if you know and trust the developer.
>
> Advanced or Back to safety

Clicking Advanced:

> Google hasn't reviewed this app yet and can't confirm it's authentic. Unverified apps may pose a threat to your personal data.
>
> Go to 'Send email' (unsafe)

It then states:

> 'Send email' wants to access your Google account
>
> This will allow 'Send email' to Read, compose, send and permanently delete all your email from Gmail
>
> Connect to an external service (Create a network connection to any external service (e.g. to read or write data)
>
> Make sure that you trust Send emails
>
> You may be sharing sensitive info with this site or app. Find out how Send emails will handle your data by reviewing its terms of service and privacy policies. You can always see or remove access in your Google Account.
>   Find out about the risks
>
> Cancel or Allow

So, for testing purposes I clicked Allow. And it all worked beautifully! And I made the form responsive, and then I remembered I had to go back and review the permissions. After 4 hours I got lost down the rabbit hole, and crawled my way back up to here in confusion. So my questions are:

1. Do I need to implement OAuth?
2. Does Google need to verify the app?
3. If yes to 2, does this take weeks? (If yes, probably need to abandon this solution)
4. If I give the app 'permissive permissions' (as I did for testing) is there any security risk?
5. If I give the app 'permissive permissions' is Google going to review it and decide to stop it running?
6. The only reason I can imagine that OAuth is needed is that data is being taken from Sheets, an email is being created and the data is being passed to that. Is it because of the data being passed to a different 'service' than collected it? Or because a different service is instructing the creation of an email? (Or both?)
7. If OAuth is implemented does this mean that users will be asked to verify? Obviously, they will not require to be logged in to use a contact form on a website.
8. Is it possible to restrict the permissions eg to only compose emails, rather than have the ability to delete any or all emails in the account (manifest?)
9. Would it make any difference if I skipped the spreadsheet ie Form to email? (Can't see how, but asking just in case.)

This is my first time using these services, so hopefully, I've explained it ok.

Any advice gratefully received!

Comment: You just need authorize the script.  The dialog is designed to scare people who don't know what they're doing not to do it.  You can always go back into your account and remove the authorization.  Of course, if the form generates a lot of submissions then you may get a lot more emails than you like.

Comment: @Cooper Thanks! So, my understanding now is because I'm the creator of the app it's safe, and because the project won't be published publicly, it doesn't need submitted to Google for review - is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > I want to use Google Form as a contact form on a website, and email the contents of the form (not just a notification) to a specified address.

---

> 1. Do I need to implement OAuth?

What you're doing is already OAuth flow. But it's managed by apps script. So, No.

> 2. Does Google need to verify the app?

Not for your use case.

> 3. If yes to 2, does this take weeks? (If yes, probably need to abandon this solution)

Maybe more

> 4. If I give the app 'permissive permissions' (as I did for testing) is there any security risk?

Anyone with access to your script(by implication, anyone with edit access to your spreadsheet) can change the script to send email from your account to any other website or Read or delete your email. So, Avoid providing edit permission to your Spreadsheet or script.

> 5. If I give the app 'permissive permissions' is Google going to review it and decide to stop it running?

Not if you're the only user.

> 6. The only reason I can imagine that OAuth is needed is that data is being taken from Sheets, an email is being created and the data is being passed to that. Is it because of the data being passed to a different 'service' than collected it? Or because a different service is instructing the creation of an email? (Or both?)

Yes.

> 7. If OAuth is implemented does this mean that users will be asked to verify? Obviously, they will not require to be logged in to use a contact form on a website.

You are the owner of the email, sheet and  the form responses. Only you need to  authorize the app/script to act on your behalf to do certain jobs like copy/paste.

> 8. Is it possible to restrict the permissions eg to only compose emails, rather than have the ability to delete any or all emails in the account

Yes.

- You can use [`MailApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app) instead of `GmailApp`
- OR Limit the [scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes) in apps script [manifest](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes) file:

  ```
  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send
  ```

> 9. Would it make any difference if I skipped the spreadsheet ie Form to email? (Can't see how, but asking just in case.)

Reducing the number of hops it takes for the script flow is good for security. But doesn't make much difference in terms of oauth flow/permissions requested. You can use the [formsubmission trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_4) in the form itself. Note however that you need to redesign the script according to the event object provided on formsubmit to the form. This is different from the event object provided to the spreadsheet onformsubmit.